# Can I retrieve the last insert id in monetdb?

Tags: sql, monetdb

I have been querying for the most recent (auto incrementing) ID of a given table I've inserted into (`SELECT "id" FROM "my_table" ORDER BY "id" DESC LIMIT 1`), but I'm wondering if there exists a more general way to do this, instead.

Comment: Which client are you using? JDBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Column

```
SELECT max ("id") FROM "my_table"
```

Get Row

```
Select * from "my table" where "id" in (SELECT max ("id") FROM "my_table")
```